# GIT Beginner Having Issues with Revert Subcommand

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm learning to navigate in GIT bash and have had issues using the "git revert" function with Bash on a MAC. I type the git executable and the revert subcommand along with the SHA: "git revert 2c881d" and I got the following error on the terminal:

```
"your local changes would be overwritten by revert.
 hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
 fatal: revert failed"
```

I have tried refreshing the console, git status, doing all I can to clear the terminal but I don't seem to have any options left. Help!

Best,

L

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that you have made changes to your files in your local working directory that have not been committed YET. The command you're about to apply will restore them to a previous state, so you are either to commit your changes or temporarily save them (somewhere) using **stash**. Try:

```
git status
```

and

```
git diff
```

… to see what has changed.

Also, be aware that `git revert` won't bring you back to a former commit in history (like Mercurial would with its same-named command), but apply a new commit that will cancel what has been done by the given commit. If you want to dismiss the last commit(s) in date, you want to look at `git reset` instead, but be aware that this command is very wide and serves multiple purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message:

```
"your local changes would be overwritten by revert.
 hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
 fatal: revert failed"
```

You have unstaged work (un-committed work), which would be over-written by revert.

You have two choices:

1) Stash your work.

- `git stash`
- Then revert your changes.
- Then unstash your work using `git stash pop`

2) Commit your unstaged work before reverting.

- `git add` unstaged files
- Commit the changes
- Revert the commit